# Read data for localstorage with Vuejs application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, vuejs3

I am trying to read data from `localstorage` in a Vue.js application.
[image: screenshot of localstorage data to fetch]

I want to have a web page that displays a table like this :
| Name  | Age  | Mail  |
|-------|------|-------|
| Name  | Age  | Mail  |
| Name2 | Age2 | Mail2 |

I tried to do this in my Vue.js program:

```
<div class="localstorage">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value, key) in store" :key="key">
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

By I don't have the table that I want. I get all the values ​​at once
[image: Screenshot of the output]

if you have any idea what i can do or or if you have any other tips?