# Read data for localstorage with Vuejs application in forma Json

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuejs3

I don't know how to do it, or is it possible to read the data of this LocalStorage with vuejs application
enter image description here

My LocalStorage is like that :

Key            value

```
1    {"Name" : "Name1", "Age":"Age1", "Mail":"Mail1" }
```

```
2    {"Name" : "Name2", "Age":"Age2", "Mail":"Mail2" }
```

I want to have a web page that displays a table like this :

| Name | Age | Mail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Age1 | Mail1 |
| Name2 | Age2 | Mail2 |

I tried to do this in my vuejs programme

```
<template>
    <div class="localstorage"> 
      <h1>Read From LocalStorage</h1>
      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Clé</th>
          <th>Valeur</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(value, key) in store" :key="key">
          <td>{{ key }}</td>
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  data() {
    return {
      store: localStorage,
      StoreJson: localStorage.getItem("1")
    }
  },
  computed: {
    localStorage() {
      return window.localStorage
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

By I don't have the table that I want. I get all the values ​​at once

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Name" : "Name1", "Age":"Age1", "Mail":"Mail1" } |
| 2 | {"Name" : "Name2", "Age":"Age2", "Mail":"Mail2" } |

if you have any idea what i can do or or if you have any other tips ?

Comment: It's definitely possible. One of the problems is you're saving each row in a separate `localStorage` prop, using a 1-based key. You might want to use one single key (e.g: `tableData` or `users` and store all data inside it). Another problem with your question is you're showing us images of code, rather than the code itself. This means anyone willing to help would need to re-type everything, instead of copy/pasting. This also makes your question *off-topic*. Ideally, you should provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Emphasis on *runnable*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take the remarks into consideration for my next publication. About the LocalStorage I can't put them in one key because I have a lot of data and if i put them in one Key application crash, but if i put them in separately it works

Comment: can u share the full component?

Comment: <template>
    <div class="localstorage"> 
      <h1>Read From LocalStorage</h1>
      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Clé</th>
          <th>Valeur</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(value, key) in store" :key="key">
          <td>{{ key }}</td>
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

Comment: edit the question instead of adding it here in the comments

Comment: <script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  data() {
    return {
      store: localStorage,
      StoreJson: localStorage.getItem("1")
    }
  },
  computed: {
    localStorage() {
      return window.localStorage
    },
  },
}
</script>

Comment: You already asked the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75005913/read-data-for-localstorage-with-vuejs-application/75014425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing your values as a json string. You need to fetch the string, convert it to a javascript object and get the keys from there:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(value, key) in store" :key="key">
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>{{ JSON.parse(value).Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ JSON.parse(value).Age }}</td>
            <td>{{ JSON.parse(value).Mail }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1"))` - LocalStorage can store only Strings and nothing else so you need to serialize and deserialize your data.

Answer (score 1):

The `keys` and the `values` stored with localStorage are always in the string format. Hence, While reading back from localStorage we should convert the JSON string into JSON object to access it's properties.

Looks like you are just adding the JSON strings into an array, It should be add into an array after parsing to JSON object.

```
this.store.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('1')))
```

Then, You can access that in template like this **:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(value, key) in store" :key="key">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.Age }}</td>
        <td>{{ value.Mail }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```